Count the number of replacements done by str_replace_all in a dplyr workflow
I have to clean a messy data frame, mostly using str_replace_all in a dplyr workflow. I would like to summarize my corrections in a table including counts of each replacement made. Ideally, str_replace_all would do this in one go, because finding these typos  (doing the replacements with str_replace_all) in a huge data frame takes quite a while.
See example:
my_str<-c('a', 'ca', 'c', 'bla')
my_df<-data.frame(my_str)
my_df

my_typo_corrections<- c(
  'a'='b'
  ,'c'='d'
  ,'what so ever' = 'whatever')

my_corrected_df <- my_df%>%
  dplyr::mutate(my_str = str_replace_all(my_str, my_typo_corrections))
my_corrected_df

I then would like to summarize my corrections in a table as such:
flextable((data.frame(my_typo_corrections) |> rownames_to_column("Typo"))%>%
            rename(Correction = 'my_typo_corrections'))%>%
  autofit()

However, I would like to add a column to the table showing the number of replacements made for each defined typo, e.g.:

Note, processing time matters to some degree.

Maybe you could combine with str_count (this is just an idea, without thinking seriously about it).

Or use a package to compare two dataframes, like versus or comparedf. But this will not exactly give what you want.

Any feedback/reaction on the provided answer? If it does solve your problem, please consider flagging it as an accepted answer so that others can benefit from it as well.

You could do sth. along these lines:
library(tidyverse)

my_df <- data.frame(my_str = c("a", "ca", "c", "bla"))

my_typo_corrections <- c("a" = "b",
                         "c" = "d",
                         "what so ever" = "whatever")

typo_counts <- names(my_typo_corrections)

names(typo_counts) <- typo_counts


my_df |>
  mutate(my_str_new = str_replace_all(my_str, my_typo_corrections)) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(counts = list(map(!!typo_counts,
                           ~str_count(my_str, .x)))) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  unnest_wider(counts)

The idea is to create a named vector for counting the occurences of your typos and then map through each of them and create a respective column in your data frame.
Note that the correct count for the correction of "a" is 3, since it appears in the first, second and last element ("a" is part of "bla").
Result would be:
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  my_str my_str_new     a     c `what so ever`
  <chr>  <chr>      <int> <int>          <int>
1 a      b              1     0              0
2 ca     db             1     1              0
3 c      d              0     1              0
4 bla    blb            1     0              0

from where you can build your table.

Thanks for your suggestion. It works, but is quite processing intense as str_replace_all and str_count do kind of the same lengthy operation of searching for a certain string in my data frame. I would prefer to avoid it, because it takes hours for my data.

There‘s no free lunch. If you want to get the info about the number of replacements you‘d need both. There might be faster approaches, but as long as you are replacing specific misspellings in a character vector and if your data is big, it takes some time. If running time is an issue, please provide a (random) example of your data that represents your data better (e.g. do you have 1m rows?).

Well, still I would not mind a free lunch. It would be possible to code str_replace_and_count_all(). Maybe in stringr 34.7.3.
